# How to delete all files from current directory including current directory?

Tags: bash, file-io, command-line, delete-directory

How can I delete all files and subdirectories from current directory including current directory?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Under bash with GNU tools, I would do it like that (should be secure in most cases):

```
rm -rf -- "$(pwd -P)" && cd ..
```

not under bash and without GNU tools, I would use:

```
TMP=`pwd -P` && cd "`dirname $TMP`" && rm -rf "./`basename $TMP`" && unset TMP
```

why this more secure:

- end the argument list with `--` in cases our directory starts with a dash (non-bash: `./` before the filename)
- `pwd -P` not just `pwd` in cases where we are not in a real directory but in a symlink pointing to it.
- `"`s around the argument in cases the directory contains spaces

some random info (bash version):

- the `cd ..` at the end can be omitted, but you would be in a non-existant directory otherwise...

**EDIT**: As kmkaplan noted, the `--` thing is not necessary, as `pwd` returns the complete path name which always starts with `/` on UNIX

Comment: what if you would like to include first a small dialog aka are you sure you want to delete this directory? and make alias for it all?

Comment: You can use rm -rfi instead of rm -rf and it will ask you "rm: remove directory `/tmp/dir_to_be_deleted'?", do you mean that?

Comment: rm -rfi would ask for every action in this directory, I was thinking something that will ask only once and delete everything.

Comment: read -n1 -p"Do you really want to delete '$(pwd -P)' [yN]?" A && if [ "$(echo $A | tr Y y)" = "y" ]; then rm -rf -- "$(pwd -P)" && cd ..
; fi

Comment: `-P` is the opposite of what I'd expect -- if I'm in a symlinked dir and I try removing it, I'd expect the symlink to be unlinked, not the original dir, and certainly not leaving a broken symlink in its place.

Answer (score 4):

```
olddir=`pwd` && cd .. && rm -rf "$olddir"
```

The `cd ..` is needed, otherwise it will fail since you can't remove the current directory.

Comment: You *can* remove the current directory.

Comment: kmkaplan, are you *sure* you can delete the current directory with rm? How many operating systems did you base that knowledge on?

Comment: wont work for a directory called --no-preserve-root for example.

Comment: dwc: yes I tested Linux, OpenBSD and MacOSX.  But I am pretty sure every Unix would do the same and I even think every POSIX system will do it.

Comment: You can in Linux (just confirmed). 

Interestingly enough, once the directory is deleted, ls -al reports "total 0" instead of something like total X, with . and .. present

Comment: deleting an open file is absolutely no problem on unix. Being in a directory is nothing more than having a file open. kmkaplan is correct!

Comment: I see:
    rm: "." and ".." may not be removed

Why not be conservative and have it work everywhere? What if this snippet gets put in a #!/bin/sh script? What if...? It's nicer to have something that works in a more portable fashion.

Answer (score 3):

```
rm -fr "`pwd`"
```

Comment: wont work for a directory called --no-preserve-root for example, too

Comment: Johannes: pwd returns an absolute path.  It will never start with dashes.

Comment: kmkaplan: sorry, thats correct! Didn't thing about that. I always use -- and most of the time it is necessary, but wiht pwd it's not.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be possible under DOS / Windows CMD, but I can't quite find a way to pipe the data between commands.  Someone else may know the fix for that?

```
FOR /F %i IN ('cd') DO SET MyDir=%i | CD .. | RD /S %MyDir%
```

Comment: This does not address the *current* directory part.

Answer (score 0):

operating system? on the *NIX-based stuff, you're looking for 'rm -rf directory/'

NOTE: the '-r' flag for 'recursive' can be dangerous!

Answer (score 0):

You just can go back the target folder's parent folder, then use 'rm -rf yourFolder'.
or you can use 'rm -rf *' to delete all files and subfolders from the current folder.

Answer (score 0):

Delete current directory with confirmation. Unlink if current dir is a symlink.

```
rmd() {
  if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
    >&2 echo "usage: rmd <dir>"
    return 1
  fi

  dir=$(realpath -se "$1") || return 2

  if [[ -L "$dir" ]]; then
    read -s -k "?Unlink '$dir'? "
    echo
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
      unlink -- "$dir"
    else
      return 3
    fi
  else
    read -s -k "?Recursively delete '$dir'? "
    echo
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
      rm -rf -- "$dir"
    else
      return 4
    fi
  fi
}

rm.() {
  rmd "$(pwd -L)" && cd ..
}
```

Usage:

```
 /tmp/tmp.29mUflkHKU                                                                                                                 base
❯ tree .
.
├── bar -> foo
└── foo

2 directories, 0 files
 /tmp/tmp.29mUflkHKU                                                                                                                 base
❯ cd bar
 /tmp/tmp.29mUflkHKU/bar                                                                                                             base
❯ rm.
Unlink /tmp/tmp.29mUflkHKU/bar?
 /tmp/tmp.29mUflkHKU                                                                                                                 base
❯ tree .
.
└── foo

1 directory, 0 files
 /tmp/tmp.29mUflkHKU                                                                                                                 base
❯ cd foo
 /tmp/tmp.29mUflkHKU/foo                                                                                                             base
❯ rm.
Recursively delete /tmp/tmp.29mUflkHKU/foo?
 /tmp/tmp.29mUflkHKU                                                                                                                 base
❯ tree .
.

0 directories, 0 files
```

Note: `read -s -k` is for `zsh`. Use `read -n1 -p` for `bash` ([source](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/readh.html))