# In Unix, how do you remove everything in the current directory and below it?

Tags: bash, unix, directory, subdirectory, delete-directory

I know this will delete everything in a subdirectory and below it:

```
rm -rf <subdir-name>
```

But how do you delete everything in the current directory as well as every subdirectory below it and the contents of all of those subdirectories?

Comment: This has to be a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550922/how-to-delete-all-files-from-current-directory-including-current-directory

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Practice safe computing.  Simply go up one level in the hierarchy and don't use a wildcard expression:

```
cd ..; rm -rf -- <dir-to-remove>
```

The two dashes `--` tell `rm` that `<dir-to-remove>` is not a command-line option, even when it begins with a dash.

Comment: Because you are specifically matching a named directory and are thus less likely to delete something that you don't intend to delete.

Comment: True. I could see myself doing that pretty easily.

Comment: doesn't it delete the directory itself too? You have to do mkdir <dir-to-remove> afterwards. But then any hardlink referring to that directory will be a distinct directory afterwards.

Comment: litb, I know I have a filesystem that allows hardlinks to directories, but I really doubt you have it too.

Comment: Agree. Note: "rm -rf ." would leave you in an undertimate state with no current directory. Unix abhors an indeterminate state.

Comment: @Joshua I have a filesystem that allows hardlinks to directories too; it's called HFS+ and anyone who is running Mac OS X 10.5 and higher has it too.

Comment: @Joshua, I wasn't aware that i can't do directory hard-links in linux with ext3. But i just tried and it didn't let me do it. Good point dude :)

Comment: To be extra safe, you need to make sure that `rm` doesn't interpret the directory name as an option: `cd ..; rm -rf -- <dir-to-remove>`

Comment: finding this now after I just deleted EVERYTHING on my server. I'm new to unix, but have a background with DOS, and the syntax is a bit different so I made a mistake. I did "rm -rf /*" intending to delete everything in the current directory, but deleted everything in root. Rackspace is restoring us now. In the future I'll keep this advice and avoid wildcards! Thanks!

Comment: @Yen, if you use `rm ./` you might accidentally type `rm . /` which could be disaster.

Comment: @MaxHodges I did something similar today on my MacBook. I accidentally did "sudo rm -R /" when trying to delete the current directory. I almost had a heart attack! Luckily, by the time I hit <CTRL> + C, it had only deleted applications A through E in /Applications. I was able to get them back easily using Pacifist and the OS X Install disk. Whew...

Comment: hmm...i thought he wanted to delete everything in the current directory, but not the directory itself...how do we do that?

Comment: To make it even safer, wouldn't you want `cd .. && rm...`. `&&` will not continue if the `cd` fails. `;` will.

Answer (score 47):

Will delete all files/directories below the current one.

```
find -mindepth 1 -delete
```

If you want to do the same with another directory whose name you have, you can just name that

```
find <name-of-directory> -mindepth 1 -delete
```

If you want to remove not only the sub-directories and files of it, but also the directory itself, omit `-mindepth 1`. Do it without the `-delete` to get a list of the things that will be removed.

Comment: I needed to delete all the files in sub-directories, but did not want to delete the sub-directories themselves. find <name-of-direcotry> -mindepth 2 -delete  worked great!

Comment: You need `-mindepth 1` if you are specifying a directory (`find <name-of-directory> -mindepth 1 -delete`). Otherwise Johannes is right it will not delete the current working directory (when using `find -delete`).

Comment: IMO, this is the best answer, particularly in scripts.

Comment: I tried:
    `find -mindepth 1 -delete`
but i got
    `illegal option -- m`
but it worked great when i removed the mindepth option
    `find . -delete`

Answer (score 44):

What I always do is type

```
rm -rf *
```

and **then hit ESC-***, and bash will expand the * to an explicit list of files and directories in the current working directory.

The benefits are:

- I can review the list of files to delete before hitting ENTER.
- The command history will not contain "rm -rf *" with the wildcard intact, which might  then be accidentally reused in the wrong place at the wrong time.  Instead, the command history will have the actual file names in there.
- It has also become handy once or twice to answer "wait a second... which files did I just delete?".  The file names are visible in the terminal scrollback buffer or the command history.

In fact, I like this so much that I've made it the default behavior for TAB with this line in .bashrc:

```
bind TAB:insert-completions
```

Comment: Missing `--` in this answer?  This approach is awesome overall I must say.

Comment: better way is run this with sudo

Answer (score 23):

Use

```
rm -rf *
```

Update: The `.` stands for current directory, but we cannot use this. The command seems to have explicit checks for `.` and `..`. Use the wildcard globbing instead. But this can be risky.

A safer version IMO is to use:

```
rm -ri *
```

(this prompts you for confirmation before deleting every file/directory.)

Comment: "Can be risky" is wondefully laconic.

Comment: When doing things like this, I've found a quick ls -r . first lets you see what you are going to delete. Useful to give a quick idea that you aren't going to delete the whole disk...

Comment: Why is it riskier than rm -rf <subdir-name>?

Comment: @liw.fi: My .bashrc typically has this: alias rm="rm -i".

Comment: @Yen -- because if you do it in the wrong place you can get disastrous results. Using a specific name in the wrong place can only go wrong if the same subdirectory happens to exist there.

Comment: Is there any possibility that it follows ".." and tries to remove parent directories? Not that i would think it would, but i better don't try it out on my box.

Comment: You cannot possibly delete the parent while residing in the child.

Comment: When I tried to run this command it failed, saying: 
rm: cannot remove `.' or `..'

Comment: Then you are left with no other option but to use the * wildcard expression.

Comment: A long time ago, I read a wonderfully inspiring story of a "rm -rf *" executed in the root directory.  The author caught it before it finished with /bin, and reconstructed the system using only commands late in the alphabet (the earlier ones having been deleted).

Comment: @David: You're probably thinking about this story: http://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~elf/hack/recovery.html

Comment: Missing `--` in this answer?

Answer (score 7):

It is correct that `rm –rf .` will remove everything in the current directly including any subdirectories and their content. The **single dot** (`.`) means the current directory. be carefull not to do `rm -rf ..` since the **double dot** (`..`) means the previous directory.

This being said, if you are like me and have multiple terminal windows open at the same time, you'd better be safe and use `rm -ir .` Lets look at the command arguments to understand why.

First, if you look at the [`rm` command man page](http://bashcurescancer.com/man/cmd/rm) (`man rm` under most Unix) you notice that `–r` means "remove the contents of directories recursively". So, doing `rm -r .` alone would delete everything in the current directory and everything bellow it.

In `rm –rf .` the added -f means "ignore nonexistent files, never prompt". That command deletes all the files and directories in the current directory and never prompts you to confirm you really want to do that. `-f` is particularly dangerous if you run the command under a privilege user since you could delete the content of any directory without getting a chance to make sure that's really what you want.

On the otherhand, in **`rm -ri .`** the `-i` that replaces the `-f` means "prompt before any removal". This means you'll get a chance to say "oups! that's not what I want" before rm goes happily delete all your files.

In my early sysadmin days I did an `rm -rf /` on a system while logged with full privileges (root). The result was two days passed a restoring the system from backups. That's why I now employ `rm -ri` now.

Answer (score 7):

How about:

```
rm -rf "$(pwd -P)"/*
```

Comment: jQuery is so powerful.

Answer (score 5):

```
rm  -rf *
```

Don't do it! It's dangerous! MAKE SURE YOU'RE IN THE RIGHT DIRECTORY!

Answer (score 4):

make **sure** you are in the correct directory

```
rm -rf *
```

Comment: This does not delete files or subdirectories whose name starts with a period.

Comment: true.  in my testing, neither does rm -rf .  tvanfosson has the best solution IMO with his "cd ..; rm -rf <dir-to-remove>"

Answer (score 2):

This simplest safe & general solution is probably:

```
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this answer is better:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12593/how-to-remove-all-the-files-in-a-directory

> If your top-level directory is called `images`, then run `rm -r images/*`. This uses the shell glob operator `*` to run `rm -r` on every file or directory within images.

basically you go up one level, and then say delete everything inside X directory. This way you are still specifying what folder should have its content deleted, which is safer than just saying 'delete everything here", while preserving the original folder, (which sometimes you want to because you aren't allowed or just don't want to modify the folder's existing permissions)